# Searching an expression in c file and an include folder using grep

Tags: grep

I want to search for some expressions in c files. I need the flow like following (like compiling).

Take one file and search in this file and its include paths.

eg: grep filname.c /root/include/*.h I tried like:

> grep "" -nHaPs /root/myfolder/test.c --include=*.h
>   /root/data/include

But it shows the results in the /root/data/include folder only. Result from /root/myfolder/test.c not showing.

The result should contain file name, line number and the line.

This works when i run as command ie

> user:/#grep "" -nHaPs -r --include=*{test.c,h} /root/test.

But no result comes when i running with system api in linux.

> system("grep \"expression \" -nHaPs -r --include=*{test.c,h} /root/test >> result.txt")

Please help

Comment: You have to escape the asterisk --> `... --include=\*.h ...`

Comment: That was a typo from me. Result comes from include header files only. Not from the file.

Comment: I have done like this: grep "<pattern>" -nHaPs -r --include=\*{test.c,h}  Thanks for all...

Comment: So is it working to you now?

Comment: this works when i run as command ie 
grep "<pattern>" -nHaPs -r --include=*{test.c,h} /root/test. But no result comes when i running with system api in linux. system("grep \"<pattern>\" -nHaPs -r --include=*{test.c,h} /root/test >> result.txt")